# How to auto redirect user to metamask for confirm the transaction in mobile with wallet connect(rainbowkit & wagmi)

Tags: walletconnect, wagmi, rainbowkit

in my dapp i'm using rainbowkit for connection, dapp working perfectly in desktop but in mobile when i connect my dapp with wallet-connect option, i have to go manually in metamask to confirm the transaction ranibowkit/wagmi not redirecting me to the metamask.

Answer (score 0):

just downgrade wagmi and rainbowkit version to -

`wagmi@0.9.5` `@rainbow-me/rainbowkit@0.8.1`

Comment: Try to use the same account you used to post the question?